# Finding a specific function...

Tags: number-theory, functions, prime-numbers

Is there a function f: N -> N such that:

$$f(p) = f(p.p) = f(p.p...p) = p$$

For a prime p/ power of a prime p has a value p
$f(a.b) = 1$. For any other integer the functional value equals 1

Does such function exist? This is not the original problem, but it should be a solution of one (in my opinion).

Comment: Tip: [MathJAX formula formatting guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Do the dots in f(p.p) mean multiplication?

Comment: Hint: Unique factorisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to express your function by using known functions you can take $f(n)=\exp(\Lambda(n))$ where $\Lambda(n)$ is the [von Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function).